# disable-output-escaping="yes" fails in try/catch

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Probably a bug in Saxon but just wanted to clarify-

```
<xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('http://something/test.txt')" 
    disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Result -

```
<div>test</div>
```

Now try-

```
<xsl:try>
 <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('http://something/test.txt')" 
    disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:catch></xsl:catch>
</xsl:try>
```

Result-

```
&lt;div&gt;test&lt;/div&gt;
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting one. Disable-output-escaping only works when you are writing output directly from the transformer to the serializer (that is, when construction of a result tree is effectively being bypassed). Within xsl:try, output can't be written directly to the serializer because of the possibility that it will need to be "rolled back" in the event that a dynamic error occurs; so it's effectively written to a hidden internal variable, whose contents are only sent to the serializer when it's known that no failure has occurred. Since disable-output-escaping is very much implementation-defined, this behaviour isn't non-conformant, but at the very least it would be reasonable to expect it to be documented.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will probably stick to just using unparsed-text-available() for now instead of using the try/catch block =)

Comment: 2018 update: for the upcoming Saxon 9.9 release, the way try/catch buffers output has been changed, and this has the consequence that `disable-output-escaping` will work, provided of course that the output of the try/catch is being written to a serializer.

Answer (score 1):

From the XSLT 3.0 specs:

> For backwards compatibility reasons, XSLT 3.0 continues to support the disable-output-escaping feature introduced in XSLT 1.0. This is an optional feature and implementations are not required to support it.